# Improving performance of SQL Query with subselects and switch cases

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write some sql query for university. It works, but it takes a lot of time to be executed ( around 6 minutes for 30k rows). Here is the query:

```
    Select  
    SalesNumber,
    CustomerID,
    od.ProductID,
    od.PricePerUnit,
       temp.Discount,
       OrderAmount,
       (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount as Total,
       ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) - (OrderAmount * StandardCost) as Profit,
       case  
         when CountryRegion = "United States" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 4 
         when CountryRegion = "Canada" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 11 
         when CountryRegion = "United Kingdom" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 5
         when CountryRegion = "Australia" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 7 
        end as TaxAmount,
        CASE WHEN temp.HasAdditionalCosts <> 0
                THEN case  
                        when sm.`name`  = "Standard Ground" then (OrderAmount * 3) + 6  
                        when sm.`name`  = "Cargo International" then (OrderAmount * 5) +  9
                        when sm.`name`  = "Oversea Deluxe" then (OrderAmount * 2) + 11 
                    end
                ELSE case  
                        when sm.`name`  = "Standard Ground" then (OrderAmount * 3)  
                        when sm.`name`  = "Cargo International" then (OrderAmount * 5) 
                        when sm.`name`  = "Oversea Deluxe" then (OrderAmount * 2)  
                    end
       END as OrderLineFreightCost,
       oh.`Status`,
       oh.OrderDate,
       oh.DueDate,
       oh.ShipDate,
       CASE WHEN oh.DueDate < oh.ShipDate 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       End as IsLateShipment
FROM db_relational.Sales as oh
INNER JOIN db_relational.SalesDetail as od ON oh.SalesID = od.SalesID
INNER JOIN db_relational.Shipping as sm ON oh.ShippingID = sm.ShippingID
INNER JOIN db_relational.Location as ad ON ad.LocationID = oh.ShipToLocationID
INNER JOIN (SELECT tempOD.SalesDetailID,
       case  
         when p.ProductCategory = "Clothing" and OrderAmount >= 5 then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.08)  
         when p.ProductCategory = "Clothing" and OrderAmount >= 10  then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.2) 
         when p.ProductCategory = "Accessories" and OrderAmount >= 5  then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.06) 
         when p.ProductCategory = "Accessories" and OrderAmount >= 10  then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.15) 
         else 0
       end as Discount,
       p.HasAdditionalCosts,
       p.StandardCost
       From db_relational.SalesDetail as tempOD
       INNER JOIN db_transformed.dm_product as p ON tempOD.ProductID = p.ProductID
) AS temp ON temp.SalesDetailID = od.SalesDetailID
```

Could someone tell me is there any way to improve performance. Am I using too many subselects and switch cases ?

Thanks!

Execution Plan:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjIJS.png)

Comment: Those `CASE` statements are cheap to compute.

Comment: Your query does not have any filtering condition. Essentially you are retrieving the whole database. That's bound to be slow. How many rows does it have?

Comment: @TheImpaler I must retrieve the whole database, because I need to extract the data from the operational database and transform them

Comment: The slowness is not related to the "switch cases" you mention; those are cheap to compute. It could be the subquery too, but my bets are on the number of rows, or a missing index. Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have added picture of execution plan. If I understood corectly it is because of subquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, **Switch cases** wouldn't affect the performance of the query too much.
But, please becareful when using **Sub Select** & **Inner Join**, unnecessary usage will increase the data traversal to make the query slower and heavier.

I found that following line is redundant:-

`INNER JOIN db_relational.SalesDetail as od`

You should remove the line and utilize the sub query as below:-

```
 Select  
    SalesNumber,
    CustomerID,
    temp.ProductID,
    temp.PricePerUnit,
    temp.Discount,
    OrderAmount,
    (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount as Total,
    ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) - (OrderAmount * StandardCost) as Profit,
   case  
     when CountryRegion = "United States" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 4 
     when CountryRegion = "Canada" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 11 
     when CountryRegion = "United Kingdom" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 5
     when CountryRegion = "Australia" then ((OrderAmount * PricePerUnit ) - Discount) * 7 
    end as TaxAmount,
    CASE WHEN temp.HasAdditionalCosts <> 0
    THEN case  
            when sm.`name`  = "Standard Ground" then (OrderAmount * 3) + 6  
            when sm.`name`  = "Cargo International" then (OrderAmount * 5) +  9
            when sm.`name`  = "Oversea Deluxe" then (OrderAmount * 2) + 11 
        end
    ELSE case  
            when sm.`name`  = "Standard Ground" then (OrderAmount * 3)  
            when sm.`name`  = "Cargo International" then (OrderAmount * 5) 
            when sm.`name`  = "Oversea Deluxe" then (OrderAmount * 2)  
    end
       END as OrderLineFreightCost,
       oh.`Status`,
       oh.OrderDate,
       oh.DueDate,
       oh.ShipDate,
       CASE WHEN oh.DueDate < oh.ShipDate 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       End as IsLateShipment
FROM db_relational.Sales as oh
INNER JOIN db_relational.Shipping as sm ON oh.ShippingID = sm.ShippingID
INNER JOIN db_relational.Location as ad ON ad.LocationID = oh.ShipToLocationID
INNER JOIN (SELECT tempOD.SalesDetailID,
       case  
         when p.ProductCategory = "Clothing" and OrderAmount >= 5 then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.08)  
         when p.ProductCategory = "Clothing" and OrderAmount >= 10  then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.2) 
         when p.ProductCategory = "Accessories" and OrderAmount >= 5  then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.06) 
         when p.ProductCategory = "Accessories" and OrderAmount >= 10  then (OrderAmount * PricePerUnit * 0.15) 
         else 0
       end as Discount,
       p.HasAdditionalCosts,
       p.StandardCost,
       tempOD.SalesID,
       tempOD.SalesDetailID,
       tempOD.ProductID,
       tempOD.PricePerUnit,
       From db_relational.SalesDetail as tempOD
       INNER JOIN db_transformed.dm_product as p ON tempOD.ProductID = p.ProductID
) AS temp ON temp.SalesID = oh.SalesID
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be your `temp` table.

You are essentially creating a new table by joining `tempOD` and `p`, and then asking MySQL to join it with everything else. The caveat is that you're most likely losing any indexes in the process.

A better way to approach the problem would be to have all the joins in a subquery, and then process the data (with `CASE` statements or any other transformations you need) in one or more outer queries. It would result in something like this:

```
SELECT PROCESS_DATA(raw_data_1), raw_data_2, ...
FROM (
    SELECT raw_data_1, raw_data_2, ...
    FROM table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON ...
    JOIN table_3 ON ...
    ...
    JOIN table_n ON ...
) tables
```